# Unable to debug react native with iOS simulator using VSCode, bundling with babel async error

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo, babeljs

I'm getting the below error when connecting to the packager from the expo app:

bundling failed: node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js: /Volumes/Tub/Work/TOYL/REACT_NATIVE/rn-complete-guide/babel.config.js: Error while loading config - You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously.

I'm new to react development, and want to use VSCode directly for debugging, not Chrome.

[image]